# Dishwasher not draining and emitting a weird sound

Tags: drain, dishwasher, pump

I have a 5 years-old Whirlpool WDT910SSYM3 dishwasher and very recently it stopped draining at the end of the washing cycle.

Every time I tried to make it drain, it emits a weird and unusual crackling sound ([see attached video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SjGZEcGuOw2rA6Y6XNnXpQmzzu0eom2R/view?usp=sharing)).

I suspect the drain pump might be damaged (I already removed it and checked everything for obstruction and I could find nothing - well... everything but the evacuation pipe, although the weird sound makes me think  the pipe is not the problem).

Before I try and find a replacement drain pump, could anyone with previous experience in this let me know if I'm on the right track?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried hooking up the pump to an external power source to check for motor operation, good bearing, etc.?

Comment: @JACK I don't have anything to actually test that: it's AC current and a very specific connector, and I would not feel comfortable toying with it.

Comment: Your brains are showing. Good for you for staying in your comfort zone.+1

Comment: Does it drain after the initial rinse cycle?

Comment: @rogerdpack I'm actually reluctant to start a complete cycle, since last time I had to drain it manually (and it was painful and quite frankly, disgusting). I however triggered the "drain" function on the dishwasher, and it emits that weird sound still.

I ordered a new pump and set-it up but sadly, the weird noise remains... I'm starting to think something is obstructing the evacuation pipe after all....

Comment: Let us know how it turns up!  You may want to convert your video to a youtube so it won't disappear...is the connection good?

Comment: @rogerdpack I actually feel silly: after changing the pump the situation remained unchanged. Then I double-checked the evacuation and it turns out it was actually completely jammed from calcium build-up. I bought a $15 replacement pipe & connectors and the damn thing restarted working better than ever. Happy ending but I should have been more thorough with my initial tests and assumptions. Lesson learnt!

Comment: Feel free to add your "own answer" here as well :)